# Using refs on a non component JS file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, ref

I have a helper function in a JS non component file which I want to export and use in my components. In this function I currently use findDOMNode to target d3graph object passed to it, but this gives a warning that the findDOMNode function is deprecated. Can you please help me refactor this to use refs?

Please see code bellow:

```
tick = (that) => {
    that.d3Graph = d3.select(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(that));
    nsp.force.on('tick', () => {
      that.d3Graph.call(updateGraph)
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the ref to the helper function:

```
const tick = (ref) => {
  ref.current.d3Graph = d3.select(ref.current);
  nsp.force.on("tick", () => {
    ref.current.d3Graph.call(() => console.log("called"));
  });
};
```

Obtaining a ref possible with `useRef` (function component) or `createRef` (classComponent)

```
const graphRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
  tick(graphRef.current);
}, [])

<D3Component ref={graphRef}/>
```